# How to click on a <a> element on a web page with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to click on this element.

```
<a href="/game.php?vil=9&amp;screen=settings&amp;action=sitter_login&amp;player=305&amp;h=417c13fb" target="_blank" class="btn">ini</a>
```

There are other elements, just like that where only the href changes. I can correctly find the  element I want. But cannot click it...
I tried the usual click() but didn't work:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[1].click()
```

Any help?

I tried this, it opens the same window, but I want to open in a new tab. I also put the internet option to open tabs with popups:

```
b=document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[1].href;
window.location.assign(b, '_blank');
```

How to open in new tab? I tried window.open() but never got to make it work:

```
window.open(b, '_blank');
```

Comment: Is it really the second element in the page?

Comment: Does this shed any light? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: Yes Jonas, its the 2nd <a> element.

Comment: Do you want the `click` event, or do you just navigate to that url? This seems like an XY problem...

Comment: Jared, Just the click.

Comment: @JaredSmith , what if I go to the URL, how should I do?

Comment: @Ruikp `window.location.href = url;`

Answer (score 0):

Following [these guidelines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) i've managed to trigger a `click` event.

```js
const action = 'click'
const event = new Event(action)
const A = document.querySelector('a')

A.addEventListener(action, e => console.log(e.target))

A.dispatchEvent(event)
```

```html
<a>Clack</a>
```

Example with multiple Anchor tags

```js
const action = 'click'
const event = new Event(action)
const AYS = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')]

AYS.forEach(A => A.addEventListener(action, e => console.log(e.target)))

AYS[1].dispatchEvent(event)
```

```html
<a>Click</a>
<a>Clack</a>
<a>Cleck</a>
<a>Clock</a>
```

Comment: If you want to get the `href` from the click event then query it from the `e` argument and set the `window.location` to the `href`

Comment: e.target.href or e.target.getAttribute('href') then window.location = (either of those)

Comment: Are you reading any documentation? I'm trying to not just give you an answer here... Please read the documentation I linked to in my answer.